# NTKRNLPA.EXE connected to strange IP

Tags: windows

Some assistance/advice needed to research this.

First: I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. If it isn't please note and I'll close.

Over the weekend my email accounts (yahoo & corporate) were locked because of invalid password.

Looking at one of my laptops (Windows XPSP3), using ProcessHacker.exe I see the process "ntkrnlpa.exe" connected to IP 205.202.182.4. Further looking up that IP points me to:

> uk    uk  lnd london  51.514999   -0.083000   dinsa ministry of defence

What other tool would someone use to inspect this?

Edit: I added some screen shots.

[image: Screenshot1_ProcessHacker]

[image: Screenshot2_ProcessHacker]

Comment: odd the whois I did on that IP address points to University of Nebraska... per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl this is a core windows component.

Comment: @RoryMcCune Besides that you can simply spoof executable names, I wouldn't trust a potentially compromised machine to produce any reliable information about what's running.

Comment: @Luc indeed I wasn't intending to suggest that the name implied trustworthiness, more that this was a known process and may well have reason to make outbound connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first investigate the IP and block further. If you do a reverse lookup, just typing `nslookup 205.202.182.4` into a command line, you'll see:

```
Name:    mil_shs_4.mil.esu3.k12.ne.us
Address:  205.202.182.4
```

[Looking the subnet up](http://who.is) in ARIN it's owned by the university of Nebraska, but the address looks like it belongs to an elementary school. So, nothing to do with the UK MoD.

So does this help you? Maybe, if you have nothing to do with a school at Murdock, Nebraska then one of their servers may be owned, and is being used as a C&C server for malware on your computer. If your system is connecting to this often then it's quite possible you've been hacked. Whether that is why your email accounts were locked is a different story, but it's reasonably likely.